# Tkinter label not show all supposed output

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

So I was code 'the row number of the nth largest value in a a column' then implement in Tkinter, but the output showed in label is not what I expected than printout in console. Suppose printout in console show value of 3 column so 3 row, but tkinter only show 1 row for 1 column.

```
def row4Nthlargest(self):
    a = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sahdan96/film_data/main/film.csv')
    b = int(self.Entry.get())
    cateogry_columns = a.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.tolist()
    integer_columns = a.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns.tolist()
    for column in a:
        if (column in cateogry_columns):
            pass
        else:
            ans= a.nlargest(b, [column]).iloc[-1]
            self.Output_gui.configure(text = ans)
```

below is my label code:

```
self.Output_gui = tk.Label(top)
self.Output_gui.place(relx=0.027, rely=0.188, height=619, width=750)
self.Output_gui.configure(background="#ffffff")
self.Output_gui.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
self.Output_gui.configure(foreground="#000000")
self.Output_gui.configure(justify = 'left', anchor ='nw')
self.Output_gui.configure(font=font11)
self.Output_gui.configure(wraplength="700")
```

[tkinter label output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR9Vn.png),
[pycharm console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdfS4.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
self.Output_gui.configure(text = ans)
```

Will overwrite any previous data. Unlike the terminal, which always appends. If you want to append in the GUI you need to change that to

```
self.Output_gui.configure(text = f"{self.Output_gui['text']}\n{ans}")
```

Comment: I tried it but its still same and keep mess my output..the result keep stack